# Staircase frequency differences of sine wave sounds - auditory adaptive oddball paradigm

Tags: psychopy

I try to create an auditory oddball experiment using PsychoPy. The standard sound should be a sine wave sound (440 HZ), the odds should be sounds at different frequencies. If the odd was detected, the difference between the odd and the standard should be smaller (or bigger if the odd was not detected) in the next trial (staircase procedure).
At the moment I have no clue on how to set up this basically very simple idea in PsychoPy.
Does anyone have a hint on how to deal with this?

Thanks in advance,

Best, Hannes

Comment: Will you be using Coder or Builder? Could you be specific about what your problem is with this? To generate the tone? To collect responses, to control the flow or to change the stimulus based on a response? Or all of them? Usually a starcase homes in on a desired value by decreasing step sizes (Hz in this case). Do you want to do that or just keep a standard step size throughout the experiment?

A good place to start would be to look at the staircases demos. In the GUI there's a menu called "demos".

Comment: Usually I use the builder to set up most of the things and then switch to the coder to change minor details. At the moment, I don't know how to set up the builder. First of all, I tried to find out if the staircase itself works for sounds, so I just picked the soundcomponent (in the properties I set sound to $level (and set every repeat), and the keyboard. At the end I put the staircase loop around it and that's it. For e.g. visual stimuli this works perfectly in that way, but not (yet) for sounds. Thus, a hint that could at least get me started would be wonderful.

Comment: So.. in order to answer your questions: in general I know how the staircase works and how it is implemented for visual stimuli, but for sound frequencies there seems to be another way, which I would like to know ;)

Comment: "For e.g. visual stimuli this works perfectly in that way, but not (yet) for sounds. Thus, a hint that could at least get me started would be wonderful."
Instead give us a hint about the way in which it doesn't work ;-) The staircase simply outputs a number that gets bigger or smaller. It doesn't know or care whether that number gets used as a contrast, frequency, duration etc. so your idea should be fine

Comment: Okay :) Wwhile I was thinking about how to describe what really happens I found the mistake: When I want to present the sounds (as I described above), I additionally presented a never ending fixation cross, which probably prevented the loop from jumping to the next level. So I fooled myself. Sorry about wasting your time.

Comment: One other thing I was thinking about: It seems, when I play a sound, that there is a little break within that sound, like a little gap or maybe the moment when the phase repeats itself. Do you know how I can avoid the little "clicking"?